# Solid way to filter lists with different values and list sizes

Tags: c#, linq, filter

what is correct and solid way to filter data from several lists which are different sizes and different values in C# language?

**I have 5 lists(example):**

1. Wire1{"HC:1", "OGB:2", "KEL:1", "ORG:8", "HAS:10" }

2. Wire2{"HC:1", "OSB:1", "KEL:1", "ORG:1", "HPS:5", "ORG:12", "HAS:25"}
3. Wire3{"HC:5", "ORB:5", "KEL:1", "ORG:2", "HPS:4", "OLG:1"}
4. Wire4{"HC:4", "OGB:2", "KEL:1", "ORG:1", "HFS:5"}
5. Wire5{"HC:1", "OGB:5", "KEL:1", "ORG:2", "HAS:5", "CCC:1", "ORC:10", "HAS:5"}

I need to check if wires have same connections(these are list elements in example above) and return them.

```
public class HarnessAndHousings  //List<HarnessAndHousings> Lists...
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string issue { get; set; }
        public string Harness { get; set; }
        public List<string> Housings { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }

public class Errors  // -> List<Errors> Output; 
    {
        public string harness { get; set; }
        public string harness2 { get; set; }
        public string housing { get; set; }
    }

//What i did is horrible but how to do that in another way correct way?

  public static void CheckErrors(List<HarnessAndHousings> harness)
        {
            foreach(HarnessAndHousings h in HarnessAndHousings)
            {
                foreach(string s in h.Housings)
                {
                    foreach(HarnessAndHousings h2 in HarnessAndHousings)
                    {
                        List<string> matches = h2.Housings.Where(x => h2.Housings.Contains(s)).ToList();

                        foreach(string m in matches)
                        {
                            Errors.Add(new Errors { harness = h.Harness, harness2 = h2.Harness, housing = m });
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(Errors.Count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can find no commonality between the example shown first and the code following it. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], with code which builds the lists as needed to demonstrate the issue you are seeing.

Comment: The last sentence that says what you need to do is not clear. What do you mean by "if wires have same connections?" That could mean so many things. The code you posted says it's checking for errors, but we don't know what that means. And it's adding to a `List<HarnessAndHousings>`. No wires. I can't make the connections (pun intended.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues or is incomplete. However, if all you're looking for is to find "wires (that) have same connections" you can use the IEnumerable's [Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) to get the matching items.

```
//Wire1{"HC:1", "OGB:2", "KEL:1", "ORG:8", "HAS:10" }
var wire1 = new List<string>();
//Wire2{"HC:1", "OSB:1", "KEL:1", "ORG:1", "HPS:5", "ORG:12", "HAS:25"}
var wire2 = new List<string>();

//matching: {"HC:1", "KEL:1" }
var matchingWires = wire1.Intersect(wire2);
```

If instead you are looking to remove duplicates from the same list, use `Distinct` like this:

```
//Wire5{"HC:1", "OGB:5", "KEL:1", "ORG:2", "HAS:5", "CCC:1", "ORC:10", "HAS:5"}
var wire2 = new List<string>();
//unique: {"HC:1", "OGB:5", "KEL:1", "ORG:2", "HAS:5", "CCC:1", "ORC:10"}
var uniqueWires = wire5.Distinct();
```

With either result list you can quickly get your error list this way:

```
var errors = matchingWires.Select(x => new Errors { //fill your object accordingly 
});
```

Please note that the above lists are only for demo purposes and are not instantiated properly.

HTH

Comment: Yes it's not complete, but that approach i saw was wrong. Because later on i would need to remove errors that were with same wires (wire1 and wire1) and after that would need to remove errors that are same (wire1 and wire2; wire2 and wire1)

Comment: @QuikBytes not sure I understand what you need but maybe you are looking for `Except` (instead of `Intersect`)? Which would produce the opposite, non-matching items.

Comment: I'll try to explain the problem :)  We get documentation from client, documentation basically is wires and their connections. But sometimes we get wrong documentation, wires can't have same connections.  So i need to check these list if there are same connections. And provide where is the error. Like my Error class.

Comment: @QuikBytes might be best if you update your post to include the expected results :) either way im positive you can leverage built-in enumerable functionality to find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unelegant solution:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var wire1 = new List<string>() { "HC:1", "OGB:2", "KEL:1", "ORG:8", "HAS:10" };
        var wire2 = new List<string>() { "HC:1", "OSB:1", "KEL:1", "ORG:1", "HPS:5", "ORG:12", "HAS:25" };
        var wire3 = new List<string>() { "HC:5", "ORB:5", "KEL:1", "ORG:2", "HPS:4", "OLG:1" };
        var wire4 = new List<string>() { "HC:4", "OGB:2", "KEL:1", "ORG:1", "HFS:5" };
        var wire5 = new List<string>() { "HC:1", "OGB:5", "KEL:1", "ORG:2", "HAS:5", "CCC:1", "ORC:10", "HAS:5" };

        var wires = new List<List<string>>() { wire1, wire2, wire3, wire4, wire5 };
        var errors = new List<string>();

        foreach (var wire in wires) {
            var otherWires = wires.ToList();
            otherWires.Remove(wire);

            foreach (var connection in wire) {
                if (otherWires.Any(x => x.Contains(connection))) {
                    errors.Add(connection);
                }
            }
        }

        errors = errors.Distinct().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", errors));
    }
```

Comment: not elegant but looks nice, but another think how errors.Distinct() works... in your situation it will work, but in my case i think it won't. But thanks i've got some thoughts looking in your example.